# Beautifulsoup text inside tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to [scrape](http://www.oddschecker.com/bookie-offers) a page with the following HTML structure:

```
<li class="bookie-offer first" data-bookie-code="BB" data-customer-type="existing" data-sport-type="2">
```

Is there any way to extract data from within the li tag? Specifically, I want to extract data-customer-type and data-sport-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

> A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag `<b class="boldest">`
>   has an attribute “class” whose value is “boldest”. You can access a
>   tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary:
>
> `tag['class']`
>
> `u'boldest'`
>
> You can access that dictionary directly as .attrs:
>
> `tag.attrs`
>
> `{u'class': u'boldest'}`

In your case...

```
>>> soup.find(class_='bookie-offer').attrs

{'class': ['bookie-offer', 'first'],
 'data-bookie-code': 'BB',
 'data-customer-type': 'existing',
 'data-sport-type': '2'}

>>> soup.find(class_='bookie-offer').attrs['data-customer-type']
'existing'
```